# How can i make a quiver or stream plot based on DeltaX and DeltaY

Tags: matplotlib, animation, coordinates, timeserieschart

I have a data set like this. I would like to make a quiver or stream plot based location, direction and time. Columns X and Y are the location of a person, ID 42386. Columns xx and yy are the directions/differences of these locations based on the earlier observation, indicating the direction the person moves. How can I use these columns to make a quiver or stream plot based on time?

```
         ID                     Time    X    Y   xx   yy 
62283  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:53.039  259  243 -1.0 -2.0
62286  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:53.280  260  242  1.0 -1.0
62289  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:53.531  258  243 -2.0  1.0
62292  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:53.721  259  241  1.0 -2.0
62295  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:54.073  263  243  4.0  2.0
62298  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:54.215  263  243  0.0  0.0
62301  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:54.555  266  242  3.0 -1.0
62304  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:54.806  268  242  2.0  0.0
62307  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:55.040  268  241  0.0 -1.0
62310  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:55.285  267  240 -1.0 -1.0
62313  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:55.533  268  242  1.0  2.0
62316  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:55.812  268  242  0.0  0.0
62319  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:56.040  267  241 -1.0 -1.0
62322  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:56.272  267  241  0.0  0.0
62325  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:56.483  267  241  0.0  0.0
62328  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:56.747  267  242  0.0  1.0
62331  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:57.072  266  240 -1.0 -2.0
62334  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:57.320  267  241  1.0  1.0
62337  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:57.559  267  240  0.0 -1.0
62340  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:57.717  267  240  0.0  0.0
62343  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:58.044  266  243 -1.0  3.0
62346  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:58.306  266  243  0.0  0.0
62349  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:58.536  267  243  1.0  0.0
62352  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:58.839  267  243  0.0  0.0
62355  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:59.006  267  243  0.0  0.0
62358  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:59.264  267  241  0.0 -2.0
62361  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:59.498  264  239 -3.0 -2.0
62364  42386  2019-07-24 08:48:59.735  262  237 -2.0 -2.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.quiver(df.X, df.Y, df.xx.shift(-1), df.yy.shift(-1))
plt.plot(df.X, df.Y)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes it is actually, and thank you very much! But now, since the movement is based on time, do you have an idea of how to indicate the time chronology in this plot?

Comment: Forget about the quiver now. How would you plan to indicate the time flow of the trajectory?

Comment: these are head movements of a single person, and i would like to know in what direction the head is tending to move, and the bigger the values of xx and yy are, the more activity level of the head moving. So the arrow distances show the activity levels and directions. I guess I would have to indicate the time either via color or written timestamps or something like that? Or maybe an animation?